# Multiple dynamic input controls with ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have to develop a configuration screen where I have to fetch a set of key pair values from db and show in the UI to update the configuration. Here, when the value is 'TRUE' or 'FALSE', I have to show the input control as checkbox and for the rest of the values, I have to show the input control as textbox. I have used ng-repeat for single input control. But here I need to show two input controls (checkbox / textbox) based on the value. Can you please give me an idea on how to use ng-repeat to implement with multiple input controls ?

Comment: show us the code that you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items"
     ng-init="item.showCb = item.value == 'TRUE' || item.value == 'FALSE'">

    <input type="checkbox"
           ng-if="item.showCb" />

    <input type="text"
           ng-if="!item.showCb" />

</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8nxvx1cn/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I have edited and worked on binding part where i am not able to bind check box properly for the first three clicks and also after three clicks though the value is updated in the model, it holds boolean value though i mentioned ng-true-value="true" and ng-false-value="false".. Please check in my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bngk/7urrobaa/

Comment: One more observation... By default when all the checkboxes are false, it works fine and only when the checkboxes are set to true by default, it causes the problem

Comment: That is because you bind to a 'true'-string, instead of a native true-boolean (`value = "true"` vs `value = true`). What you can do instead is set the `ng-true-value="'true'"` with quotes (also for the false value). See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7urrobaa/7/)